# How to run multiple OS simultaneously on different cores of ARMv8

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, virtualization, multicore

I have an ARM Cortex-A53 based embedded system which has 4 cores. It is not implemented with ARM TrustZone.

Is it possible to run the following OSs simultaneously?

Core0:Some type of RTOS
Core1:Some type of RTOS
Core2 and Core3: Linux

All of them use some shared memory space to exchange data.
Boot sequences until loading image(monolithic RTOS and Linux kernel) into DDR are processed by external chip.

Do I need to use a hypervisor, or just treat all cores as independent logical CPUs?
I am not familiar with ARMv8, should I pay additional attentions in setting MMU, GIC, etc. in my case?

Comment: In general no (without hypervisor). A OS is not just running a core, but handling hardware, IO, clock, interrupts (e.g. the timer to switch from one task to an other). All of them will conflict each other. You can use hypervisor, but... you get much penalties. A raspberry pi is cheap (and it had Cortex-A53)

Comment: It can be done both ways. Depends on the use case. If security is a concern then hypervisor is the way to go otherwise frameworks like OpenAMP or MEMF can be used to run multiple OSs on different cores cooperatively.
I did similar work once without hypervisor. The configuration was a bit different, core 0: RTOS and core123: Linux. Board was zcu102. I had to patch different areas of both RTOS and Linux to get it done.
It was based on OpenAMP, so my RTOS (master) was supposed to load the Linux(remote) image and run it on core 1 and then create a communication channel using rpmsg.

Comment: Some areas that you will need to look into if running things without hypervisor are
1- Only one OS should initialize the distributor interface of gic.
2- Each OS will need a different timer. In my case, ZCU102 provides additional timers so I used those in RTOS and Linux used ARM generic timer.
3- Remove the peripherals assigned to RTOS from Linux dts and also the memory regions being used by RTOS.
4- I don't remember exactly, but Linux uses some of the SGIs (software-generated interrupts) for internal use. You might want to look into it if you are planning to add some type of communication

Comment: @R.k. Lohana: [According to ARM](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102379/0000/What-is-the-Generic-Timer-?lang=en) , each core has its own set of architectural timers. The need for different timers should therefore not be an issue.

Comment: @Frant, my bad. Thanks for pointing it out. I actually had two more RTOS instances running on Cortex-R5 cluster on the same SoC, there I had to use the additional timers. For Cortex A53 - Core 0 RTOS instance, I used arm generic timer.

Comment: @R.k. Lohana:  Should I change the EL(Exception level)s?

Comment: @yoyozi: Normally RTOS is supposed to run in EL1 and same goes for Linux. Hypervisor runs in EL2. From what I remember Linux will auto transition to EL1, after some bare minimal initialization of EL2 register. Some RTOSs do that as well. Another thing is Linux boot process requires dtb to be already loaded in ram and its address to be stored in one of the core registers before running it.
This is done by a bootloader like uboot. uboot also transition to EL1 if configured to do so before jumping to Linux. So basically it depends on your overall system and bootflow and bootloader and stuff.

Comment: @R.k.Lohana Excuse me for bothering. Do you have some implementation examples about how to `3- Remove the peripherals assigned to RTOS from Linux dts`?

Answer (score 1):

That's a very-very vague question, so answer gonna be the same sort.

That's how ARMv8 looks like.

[image]

> Is it possible to run the following OSs simultaneously?

Yes, there should not be restrictions for that.

> All of them use some shared memory space to exchange data.

Yes, you could map same region of physical memory to all of them. How to sync access to that shared memory from different OSs (eg isolated from each other environments) is more important question though.

> Boot sequences until loading image(monolithic RTOS and Linux kernel)
> into DDR are processed by external chip.

For sure you should have an image of OS in memory before passing control to Kernel entry. So should be done from EL3 or EL2.

> Do I need to use a hypervisor, or just treat all cores as independent
> logical CPUs?

Yes, you do need hypervisor. That's probably the best way to organise interaction between different OSs.

> should I pay additional attentions in setting MMU, GIC, etc. in my
> case?

There are MMU for each EL. So MMU-EL0 are totally independent. MMU-EL1 (OS/Kernel) to organise interaction between App in same OS. MMU-EL2 (hypervisor) to organise interaction between different OS. But all in all probably not something special.

GIC, that's depends on how you are gonna organise interrupts. It's possible to route interrupts to all cores or only particular one. Use them to change EL and select which OS is gonna to handle it. So yes, GIC might need quite an attention.